# Visualize a 3D label matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D label matrix resulted from a 3D image stack. I have also created a 3D label using the free code (label2rgb3D) available at https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8355-label2rgb3d. I want to visualize the final 4D matrix with distinct colours for the respective labels in a 3D space. Appreciate if someone can guide me through.

I can easily do this with a 2D label matrix.

```matlab
a = randi([0, 1], 10, 10);
b = bwlabeln(a, 4);
r = label2rgb(b, 'jet');
figure;
imshow(r);
```

but in the 3D, I am stuck after the first label creation.

```matlab
a = randi([0, 1], 10, 10, 10);
b = bwlabeln(a, 26);
r = label2rgb3d(b); % a 4D matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to R2019a, the volumeViewer app in MATLAB supports visualization of categorical data and label matrices.

```
volumeViewer(categorical(rand(100,100,100) > 0.5))
```

If you have access to R2019a, you can also use the function labelvolshow which is a more stripped down interface that opens the volume in a MATLAB figure window that can be printed/exported.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/labelvolshow.html

Comment: It says "Windows Software OpenGL support does not meet the minimum requirement of this app". Is there another way to possibly do this?

Comment: I ran this in the code in a mac and gave me what I wanted. However, I am not able to extract an image from the volumeViewer.

Another method is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have R2019a, you can use labelvolshow. The examples in labelvolshow demonstrate how to export the displayed volume to an image file format.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. This works on Matlab online. But I have 2018b with me. And I think it is not possible to get the 3D axis on the image using Labelvolshow.